# tf transformPoint() equivalent on tf2?

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It used to be that, with tf, we would use a `TransformListener` and its `transformDATA()` methods, e.g.

```
import tf
listener = tf.TransformListener()
...
ptNew = listener.transformPoint('frameNew', ptOld)
```

but now with tf2 (i.e. tf2_ros), there doesn't seem to be a `transformPoint()`.  The only place I can find something close is in `tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_point()`, which requires PyKDL (not installed by default with ROS).  I can't find any docs on the api for the `do_transform_DATA()`, however, and I see that the code is called "geometry_experimental" on github.  Am I just trying to use this before it's ready for prime time, or is there something I'm missing as far as docs and using the tf2 listener?

Edit: Bump. I'm also facing this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95791/tf-transformpoint()-equivalent-on-tf2?/) by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-06-19**:
Is there an update on this? Transforming points from one coordinate system to the other is, for me, the essential use-case of tf2. But it seems that this is supported only poorly and documented even more poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the `transform` or `transform_full` methods from the [BufferInterface](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/indigo-devel/tf2_ros/src/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.py#L37) on any datatype which implements `do_transform`

`tf2` is now recommended. It is still in the geometry_experimental repository but only for legacy reasons.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-12-14**:
hey @tfoote, I tried using the `transform` method to transform a stamped pose, and got this error:
`File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.py", line 43, in transform do_transform = self.registration.get(type(object_stamped))`

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-12-14**:
`File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.py", line 105, in get raise TypeException('Type %s if not loaded or supported'% str(key)) TypeException`

**Comment by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) on 2017-03-07**:
For anyone that comes across this, to transform PoseStamped messages you can try installing ros-kinetic-tf2-geometry-msgs and then importing tf2_geometry_msgs

**Comment by [Alkrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/71631/alkrick/) on 2021-03-08**:
Is there an update on this? I am following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) tutorial and can't figure out the tf2 equivalent of the listener.transformPoint() part, I tried including buffer_interface.h but the methods mentioned above were still not available

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is very tricky. I had to do

```
 import tf2_geometry_msgs.tf2_geometry_msgs
```

in order for the `do_transform` interfaces for `PoseStamped` and other geometry_msgs messages to be registered.
The registration is done while importing as shown [in the source code for tf2_geometry_msgs.py](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/c73b5939723db078c9bbe18523230ad54f859682/tf2_geometry_msgs/src/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.py#L39).

The comments by @Procópio  and @Alkrick can be resolved by this.

This does not appear (from an end-user's perspective) to be relevant for the `transform` function. Either documentation should say this or the way to use `tf2_ros` should be improved (why not import the above automatically when doing `import tf2_ros`?)

---

Originally posted by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) with karma: 178 on 2022-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1